# Having Multiple Facebook ads use one conversion pixel

Tags: facebook, advertising, conversions

Can't wrap my head around if this will work or not. Don't want to launch a campaign til I know for sure.

I want to run five separate ads with all different target audiences. When clicked, each of these ads all direct to the same webpage where the goal is to get the visitor to click a button to be sent to Amazon and buy a product. I want to set up a conversion pixel to fire when this button is clicked.

My confusion is if the button is clicked, how does Facebook know/track which ad this conversion came from? And subsequently give me insight into which ad is performing the best?

Comment: Referrer. Example in php: `echo $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']; print_r($_SERVER)`

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, a single Facebook conversion tracking pixel works fine to measure the performance of multiple ads. In case you don't trust this answer, feel free to create a conversion pixel for each ad. Don't forget to connect the pixel to the ad. When you are using for instance Google Tag Manager, it's easy to add/remove conversion pixels